# ggplot2 geom_bar graph of counts per month

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, geom-bar

New to R and trying to make a graph of counts that sums up the month a book was finished.

[image: This is the column of dates that I am pulling from]

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot)

book_finished_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = mon)) +
  geom_bar(aes('Book finished'), width = 30) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", 
               labels = date_format("%m"))
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))
```

`book_finished_plot`

Which gives me the error code: `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Comment: It seems possible that `data$mon` is `character` (ie text string) data and not formatted as `Date`. If that's the case, `aes(x = as.Date(mon))` would fix it or you could fix upstream when you load the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  mutate(`Book finished` = as.Date(`Book finished`) |> floor_date("month")) |> # group by month and year
  ggplot() + 
    aes(x = `Book finished`) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count", fill = "#f48225") + 
    # decoration stuff below
    labs(title = "Books finished by month", x = "Month", y = "Number of books") + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#2d2d2d"),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#2d2d2d"),
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          axis.text = element_text(color = "white"),
          text = element_text(color = "white"))
```

[image]

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(`Book finished` = c("2023-01-03", "2023-01-10", 
"2023-03-04", "2023-03-19", "2023-04-02", "2023-04-01", "2023-04-06", 
"2023-04-23", "2023-05-21", "2023-05-18", "2023-05-26", "2023-06-01", 
"2023-06-05", "2023-06-07", "2023-06-09")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```